# Minimal Install -> Headset not working

Tags: sound, alsa, headset

everyone!

I am having some trouble making my headset work with my newly installed (minimum install) Ubuntu.

I have done some googling about it, but I still can't fix it.

This is alsamixer:
[image: Alsamixer config]

Note that speaker is muted, which is fine. When I change from headset output to speaker output, the sepaker is unmuted and the headphon is muted, then the sound comes from the speakers.

This is pavucontrol(installed after the advice of @laugeo:
[image: Pavucontrol]

Notice that on the last output device it recognizes that there is something pluged in, but still no sound coming out.

But I can't make the sound come from the headset!

Comment: which  pc model ? multiple headphone are strange , try pavucontrol  (to be installed sometimes)  : in output device tab,   look if you have multiple headphone in port list , and test them one by one .

Comment: Thanks for your reply, mate. I installed pavucontrol, but still no sound coming out. The printscreen was added to the question. Would you mind taking a look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally understood what the problem was!

Somewhy, Ubuntu has 2 different input options, Headset and Headphones. I guess because of the microfone, I have to choose headset.

(Sorry for the quality of the picture, I coudn't take a print screen with options opened)

[image: Settings -> Sound]